# Lua: How to check if a string contains only numbers and letters?

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, alphanumeric, non-alphanumeric

Simple question may have a simple answer, but my current solution seems horrible.

```
local list = {'?', '!', '@', ... etc)
for i=1, #list do 
    if string.match(string, strf("%%%s+", list[i])) then
         -- string contains characters that are not alphanumeric.
    end
 end
```

Is there a better way to do this.. maybe with string.gsub?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "strf"? And what is `$list`? That's not a valid Lua operator.

Comment: Something that I created, it's shorthand for string.format.

Comment: Typed it a little too fast without looking back, it's fixed :P

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you're looking to see if a string contains only alphanumeric characters, then just match the string against all *non-alphanumeric* characters:

```
if(str:match("%W")) then
  --Improper characters detected.
end
```

The pattern `%w` matches alphanumeric characters. By convention, a pattern than is upper-case rather than lowercase matches the inverse set of characters. So `%W` matches all non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a set match with `[]`

```
local patt = "[?!@]"

if string.match ( mystr , patt ) then
    ....
end
```

Note that character classes in lua only work for single characters (not words).
There are built in classes, `%W` matches non-alphanumerics, so go ahead and use that as a shortcut.

You can also add the inbuilt classes to your set:

```
local patt = "[%Wxyz]"
```

Will match all non-alphanumerics AND characters `x`, `y` or `z`

Answer (score 1):

I use this Lua two-liner:

```
  local function envIsAlphaNum(sIn)
    return (string.match(sIn,"[^%w]") == nil) end
```

When it detects a non-alphanumeric it returns false